# Get copy of some protected files system windows with Python?

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, privileges

I am working on a forensics project with python and I need the copy of some files like C:\hiberfile.sys, C:\swapfile.sys, C:\$MFT ...

Even running the script with administrator rights gives a permission denied.
Is there a way to bypass this issue?

```
files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, '*.sys'))
            for file in files:
                if os.path.isfile(file):
                    shutil.copy2(file, collectionPath)
```

Comment: Boot from a live USB?

Comment: No, the system locks or denies access to certain special files from user mode -- even from a process that's running as SYSTEM. A forensic analysis of a filesystem uses the raw volume data and directly parses filesystem data structures.

Comment: @ErykSun, so there is no way I could get those copies? maybe running those functions (that copy the files) as SYSTEM!

Comment: No, as I already said, running as SYSTEM will not help. Access to active paging files is not allowed, and the NTFS driver denies access to its system files such as "$Mft".